# If UICollectionView does not have enough cells to fill a row, make the first row incomplete not the last

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

Essentially I have a collection view with all cells the same size.  If the last row is incomplete (as in, it doesn't have a fully filled out row) the collection view fills the last row with empty cells, like A in the image below.  **How can I get my collection view to look like B, where the incomplete row is the first row instead of the last?**

[image]

I'm in this situation because I had to rotate my `CollectionView` 180 degrees so that the newest added items are at the top, not the bottom, so rotating or flipping the collection view again would not solve my problem.  (When fixed to look like B, new items added to the collection view would technically go in the spot to the left of 1.)

Would a better fix have been to not flip the `CollectionView` at all and just redo the rest of my app's logic regarding adding new items and maintaining their indices?  `UICollectionView`'s are my weak point when it comes to iOS programming...

**EDIT:** Fixed my problem via a workaround.  I flipped the order of the data source of the collection view, it worked for my situation.  Leaving question open however since I didn't solve it per se.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add another row with an empty content and load it at the start.

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem since I want the row to be partially filled with elements, not completely empty.